# bash: how to redirect the result in to another file

Tags: bash, unix

Now I have this code, which can show the result on my terminal

```
 cat temp | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

but How can I redirect this into another file?

I tried this `echo temp | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }' > temp2`, but not working

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo temp | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }' > temp2
```

You used echo:

```
cat temp | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }' > temp2
```

Also you don't need to use cat:

```
sort -n temp | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }' > temp2
```

Answer (score 1):

Any command that displays results to your terminal can be redirected to a file by adding to the end of the command a redirect:   > out.txt

```
cat temp | sort -n | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'  > temp2
```

Your second attempt (echo temp ...) simply sent the string "temp" to the sort command, which sent it to the uniq command, and so fort. echo temp is not a valid way to direct results of file "temp". echo prints the actual string "temp" to the terminal and has nothing to do with the file "temp"

```
[root@www ~]# echo THIS IS FILE CONTENTS > temp
[root@www ~]# cat temp
THIS IS FILE CONTENTS
[root@www ~]# echo temp
temp
[root@www ~]# cat temp > temp2
[root@www ~]# cat temp2
THIS IS FILE CONTENTS
[root@www ~]#
```